# PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed while creating Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure

Below code is to create a procedure passing some values and then an insert operation happens in_no_tiers times

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_TIER_INFO(in_lp_code IN VARCHAR2 , in_tier IN VARCHAR2 , in_pts_reqd IN VARCHAR2 , in_multiplier IN VARCHAR2 , in_no_tiers NUMBER)
AS
    low_bound NUMBER := 0 ;
    current_tier VARCHAR2(32) ;
    current_points NUMBER ;
    current_multiplier NUMBER ;
    upper_bound NUMBER := in_no_tiers ;
    curr_level NUMBER := 0 ;
    seperator VARCHAR2(2) := "," ;

BEGIN
    FOR j IN low_bound..upper_bound LOOP
    current_tier  := split(in_tier , seperator , j) ;
    current_points := TO_NUMBER(split(in_pts_reqd , seperator , j)) ;
    current_multiplier := TO_NUMBER(split(in_pts_reqd , seperator , j)) ;

    INSERT INTO TIERED_LOYALTY_PROGRAM(LP_CODE, STATE,TIER1,POINTS_REQUIRED, MULTIPLIER, LEVEL1)
    VALUES (in_lp_code , 0 , current_tier  , current_points , current_multiplier , j) ;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

This procedure calls another custom function split which will take values in string form eg: 'R1 , R2 , R3 ' and returns 'R1' or 'R2' or 'R3' based on whether the 3rd argument in func is 0 , 1 or 2. This func is running properly but procedure is throwing many errors

```
Errors: PROCEDURE INSERT_TIER_INFO
Line/Col: 9/12 PL/SQL: Item ignored
Line/Col: 9/28 PLS-00201: identifier ',' must be declared
Line/Col: 13/2 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 13/35 PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
Line/Col: 14/3 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 14/51 PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
Line/Col: 15/2 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 15/54 PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
```

Comment: Please, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA): *' ' are two **single quotation marks** that begin and end text literals*

Answer (score 1):

Your problem starts here:

```
Line/Col: 9/12 PL/SQL: Item ignored
Line/Col: 9/28 PLS-00201: identifier ',' must be declared
```

That's this line of code:

```
seperator VARCHAR2(2) := "," ;
```

Use single quotes to identify a string value. Double quotes are for object identifiers or column aliases.

```
seperator VARCHAR2(1) := ',' ;
```